# populating second select based upon first select options

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have a multiselect and the code i am trying is to populate the second select from the query data i will getting, like making an ajax call to the function and that function will append or remove the entries from the select

i triedsomething like this

```
$(document).ready(function{
    $("#desk").change(function() {
        var deskid = $("#desk :option").attr('id');
        $.ajax ({
            url: mypagephp?dataid=deskid // [acomma seperated values of the all above chosen desks]
        });
    });
});
```

my html code is like this

```
<tr>
    <td width="19%">Desk</td>
    <td width="81%">
        <select name="desk" id="desk" multiple="multiple" class="select">
            <cfoutput query="getAllDesk">
                <option value="100" id="100">Test 1</option>
                <option value="101" id="101">Test 2</option>
                <option value="102" id="102">Test 3</option>
                <option value="103" id="103">Test4</option>
            </cfoutput> 
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

but i think i am losing some way where i need to do a each call and nest the ajax call inside the each call so i can pass the mutiple entries to the ajax cal as comma seperated and it can populate the second select

Comment: So you're trying to do a multi-select using a dropdown?  Why not use checkboxes?  Perhaps I'm not fully grasping what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use checkboxes from what it sounds like you're trying to do.  The following code will give you an array of all selected options and then you join then with a comma to get the string you want to send via AJAX.

```js
$('#desk').on('submit',function(){
  //this will loop through checked boxes and put them in the
  //'checkedValues' variable as an array
  var checkedValues = $(this).find(':checkbox:checked').map(function(){
    return this.value;
  }).get();
  //then join the array and you'll have your comma separated string
  //with all selected values
  var desksString = checkedValues.join(',');
  console.log(desksString);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="desk">
  <input type="checkbox" value="100" name="desk1"/>Test 1<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="101" name="desk2"/>Test 2<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="102" name="desk3"/>Test 3<br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: but i am not checkboxes, i a, using a select

Comment: Could you be more clear on what you're trying to do?  So you want it to be that with each option you select in the drop down, it gets added to the string to be sent to the server?  Will this string be sent every time a new option is selected or only when a submit button is clicked?  Select elements aren't intended for multiple selects, hence why I think going with checkboxes would be more ideal.  I can amend my answer if you can clarify.

Comment: yes sure, If i have A selected at Top i mean 1st select and then I must select either A1 or A2 because A is Present in 2nd select as optgroup. So yes, Second is getting generating dynamically as to what you select from 1st one, if u unselect from 1st select it will be removed from the secon select too and the second select is rebuild from the query again. every time item is selected from 1st one, i am rebuilding the 2nd select, i know this sounds bad, but this is what i went for and if checkboxes are a solution, i can revert code to checkboxes instead

Comment: So basically, you wanna do an AJAX call to the server when the first select box choice is made which returns the data you want populated in the second select box?